# R stats.dll in Excel

Tags: r, excel, dllimport

I am trying to declare a function in Excel for the CDF of a noncentral t distribution using the R stats library. I have unsuccessfully tried variations of the following to declare the function `pnt`. How would I go about doing this successfully?

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function pnt Lib _
  "C:/Users/User/Documents/R/R-4.1.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll" ()
```

Comment: You need to create your own DLL that Excel will call, and that DLL links to R routines using the instructions in section 6.17 of the Writing R Extensions manual.  The `stats.dll` DLL is  set up to be called from R using R functions `.C()`, `.Fortran()` or `.Call()`, not to be called from an external program.